# How can I make TChart bootom axis as date with day as 8 h(no 24h ) with Gantt series

Tags: delphi, teechart, gantt-chart

In my application day of work is 8h so I would like planing and showing status machines in 8 h. In 24 h day I waste 2/3 space on chart.

When I add Gantt element to the chart every day is represent by 24hour. 
So if tasks are: 
1: 6.00 to 14.00 in 28.06.2015, 
2: 6.00 to 12.00 in 29.06.2015,
3: 6.00 to 10.00 in 30.06.2015,
and woreker shift from 6 to 14, Chart.BottomAxis.SetMinMax ( '28.06.2015', '30.06.2015');
from foreman point of view worker has: 0h 28, 2h 29, 4h 30; hours free and foreman can add additional work. 
But on the chart he can see 24 minus time task.

Comment: What's the question here? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate the empty gaps in the horizontal axis, you could try doing something as the *All Features\Welcome!\Chart Styles\Financial\Axis Labels no Weekends* example in the *Tee9New.exe* demo included with TeeChart Pro installers and available at http://www.steema.com/download/vcl